# Are $G/A$ and $G/B$ isomorphic if $A$ and $B$ have the same order?

Tags: finite-groups

Are $G/A$ and $G/B$ isomorphic if $A$ and $B$ have the same order?

I think so but want to confirm. Let $G$ be finite.

Comment: No, it's "very" false - why don't you try to think up some examples?

Comment: @peterag Okay, thanks for the reply. I may still be off, but would it be true if we added that $G/A$ and $G/B$ are both simple?

Comment: That would amount to the claim that finite simple groups of the same order are isomorphic, which is not true.